# How to match text between headers (formatted as number and title)?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to extract the paragraphs between Result and Conclusion from a research paper using regular expressions. For the following sample, the emphasized paragraphs between "6. Results" and "7. Conclusion" should be matched.

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec fermentum orci nec felis. Sed sollicitudin diam id sapien.
>
> 6. Results
>
> *Ut libero. Vestibulum quam libero, malesuada et, ornare id, aliquet id, tellus.*
>
> *Nullam dapibus viverra quam. Vestibulum sit amet nunc vel justo dictum pharetra.*
>
> 7. Conclusion.
>
> Duis imperdiet venenatis purus.

I tried this and it the output is `None`

`x = (re.match(r'^[0-9]\s(Result)\.(.*?)^[0-9]\s(Conclusion)', text))`

How could the Python `re` module be used to extract the paragraphs? This assumes regexes are the most appropriate tool, but they're not required for answers.

Comment: Can you not just select the text with the mouse and copy it?

Comment: Why did you include a second `^`, or any `^` at all?

Comment: Do you know the difference between `re.match` and `re.search`? (If not, look it up. You might need to use `re.search`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](/q/159118/90527)", "[What is the difference between re.search and re.match?](/q/180986/90527)", "[Python and "re"](/q/72393/90527)"

Comment: I can’t just select the text because the input as a research paper could be any paper. I just want to extract the results and present it as the output. I don’t know much about regex, I tried whatever I could find here from other answers but I couldn’t find anything suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

instead of using regex, you could also just try splitting the document into a list of strings. Then just combine elements and add them to a new list until you hit a section header. Maybe something like this:

```
blocks = []

with open('researchpaper.txt', 'r') as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  block = ''
  for line in lines:
    if re.match('^d*\.\s.*'):
      blocks.append(block)
      block = ''
    else:
      block += line
```

Comment: I will try this. Will this help me extract the paragraphs after Result header?

Comment: yea thats the intent